# nginx - reverse proxy certificate authentication

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy

I´m trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy to an internal webserver running Tomcat, which hosts a front-end to our ERP system.

It is already working fine: I can perfectly connect to the nginx server (which is locked up on our network, different VLAN, firewall, etc etc etc) and then reverse proxy to my ERP server.

However, I want do add an extra layer of protection, by requiring users to have a digital certificate on their computer, so they can access the first (nginx) server. The certificate is not used/necessary to the back-end server.

I´ve been through this tutorial 
http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi
which allowed me to generate my self-signed certificates and everything else.

When using **ssl_verify_client optional** on nginx configuration, I can connect normally to my back-end server, but no certificate is asked/required.

When I switch it to **ssl_verify_client on** , all access are then blocked by a

```
400 Bad Request

No required SSL certificate was sent
```

No matter which browser I am using (Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox). Of course I´ve put all certificates/chain on my client computer, but no certificate is asked on any browsers. What I am missing?

Here is my full nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        server_name 103vportal;

        ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/certs/senha.txt;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.3.0.244:16030;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_send_timeout 300;
        }

}
```

Comment: Your client certificate is signed by the `ca.crt` and is listed under your *Personal Certificates* in the browser? And you have cleared the browser cache since reconfiguring the server?

Comment: @RichardSmith hi there, thanks for the help. Yes, it is signed by ca.crt as per the tutorial. However, it is really strange as even forcing (Internet Explorer certs) it does not list under Personal Certificates, but under Intermediate Authorities. I also noticed this, but I followed the tutorial to the letter, since this is my first time implementing this. Maybe the cert is not "client/personal" ? Any way to generate it through the openssl ?

Comment: I create a PKCS#12 file with a password to get the private key and the signed certificate into the browser's list of personal certificates. The intermediate certificate store will not work for you.

Comment: do you know the command to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have generated a private key and a certificate request for your user and signed it with your client CA. You need to get the private key and the signed certificate into the list of personal certificates in the browser.

I have found that the best way is to create a password protected PKCS#12 (as some browsers insist on password protection). I use the following OpenSSL command:

```
cat user.key user.crt | openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.p12
```

Comment: dear sir, thanks for your help so far. I´ve deleted all certificates and did it all over again (following the same tutorial) and I´ve used your command and it really made out the user cert. I were able to import it on Internet Explorer under personal certificates. The entire certificate chain appears as valid, however, I still get the same 400 bad request error, and no popup on the browsers asking me to choose the certificate or something like. On Nginx log, I can see this (same as before) ' [info] 1396#0: *13 client sent no required SSL certificate while reading client request headers, "'

Comment: Does IE trust your server cert or the CA which signed your server's cert? Some browsers will not exchange personal certs with sites they do not trust (not sure about IE)

Comment: yes, i´ve manually put the CA under trusted root certificates.

Comment: I managed to get it working. I created all certificates again (for the 5th time  if I remember...) and this time, I´ve created all certs with my internal hostname ("103vportal" in this case). After that, I´ve manually created a DNS record on my server to this hostname. Put everything together (including the cert created with your command) in my browser and this time, IE and Chrome shown a popup for me to choose the certificate. And worked. So apparently,it was something with the hostname/cert combo. Since it works for me, I won´t mess around, but later I´ll try creating again with my name. Tks